# Transformation of C++ code from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: c++

I am using VS 2008. I compile my C++ code in 32 bit compiler. I am using DialogBoxParam to create a GUI and its working fine. But the same code is compiled in 64 bit compiler,  I get error that error `C2664: 'DialogBoxParamA' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'DLGPROC'`. Kindly help me with this

Comment: I have made those changes. Still I get same error

Comment: If "those changes" refers to a specific answer, add the comment to that answer instead of the question. I think you're referring to Joachim's answer, and obviously you would not get the exact same answer if you had indeed applied his change.

Comment: Yes, I referred to Joachim's answer, I did not get any solution

Comment: Well at least you didn't get an error about `BOOL ... ` since Joachim told you to change that to `INT_PTR ...`

Comment: No, I get same error as I mentioned in my question

Comment: Then you in fact did not make that change, even if you think you did.

Comment: This is What I had done. I changed my receiving parameter to INT_PTR. Before I declared as INT.

Comment: I've got no idea what a "receiving parameter" is. And as Joachim noted, you should change the return type. Show us that declaration, and the actual call.

Answer (score 7):

If you check e.g. [this `DLGPROC` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will see that it should return [`INT_PTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#INT_PTR) and not [`BOOL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#BOOL).

The problem you have stems from the fact that `BOOL` is a type-alias of `int` which is 32 bits on both 32- and 64-bit platforms using the Visual Studio compiler. `INT_PTR` on the other hand is 64 bits on 64 bit systems, making you have a mismatch in return type.

Change the return type of the dialog function to the correct `INT_PTR` and it should work on *both* 32 and 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are compiling on a 32 bit machine, the usual problem with moving to a 64 bit machine is that a long and an int are both 32 bits on a 32 bit platform, while a long is 64 bits and an int is 32 bits on the 64 bit platform. If you are using pointer referencing or byte manipulation, this can cause difficulties in the call to your functions.

You need to examine the actual processing involved.